# API is accessible from other routes than my frontend-url

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, windows-authentication

I am developing an intern web app for our company. Because it is being used just in our company we desided to implement windows authentication. The problem is that if I am logged in, I can just open a new tab with an api and I will get the data.

I've tried adding some cors attribute for restrictiction but this didn't work for me neither.

Authentication.cs:

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("login")]
    public IHttpActionResult AuthenticateUser() {
      return GetHttpActionResult(() => {
        WindowsPrincipal user = RequestContext.Principal as WindowsPrincipal;

        if (user != null) {
          return _viewModelFactory.CreateEmployeeViewModel(_timeTrackingPersistenceManager.GetEmployeeByUserName(User.Identity.Name));
        } else {
          return Content(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "This user cannot be logged in");
        }
      });
    }
```

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
      config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));

      // Web API routes
      config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "DefaultApi",
          routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
          defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
      );

      ConfigureCors(ref config);
    }

    public static void ConfigureCors(ref HttpConfiguration config) {
      string frontendAddress = "";

#if DEBUG
      frontendAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["frontendPathLocal"];
#elif !DEBUG
      frontendAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["frontendPathServer"];
#endif
      var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(frontendAddress, "*", "*") { SupportsCredentials = true };
      config.EnableCors(cors);

      config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
    }
```

Everything works as expected exept the fact that I can access data from another page other than my frontend.

Comment: CORS doesn't have any effect when going to an api endpoint directly. The only time CORS would do anything is if the API endpoint was accessed via a an ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cors will not do anything if you are accessing the url directly in the browser. If you want an access only from your application you cannot have ordinary windows authentication, since as you say everyone has access to it.

What you can do is run you frontend application as a special service account and limit access only to this account in your backend.

If your frontend is running directly in the browser, and you would like to access API, then I doubt there is any way to "protect" API additionally. I.e. if a user has access via your site with AJAX there is nothing stopping them from doing it directly unless you add some magic token, but since it is running in the browser, user will always be able to emulate exactly the same request to API directly.

P.S. Why is this a problem that users can access API directly? Apparently they have rights to do everything API allows anyway, but if you want to do it ONLY through your own GUI you will have to provide additional layer of security on the server side that will use it's own service account as I described above.

Comment: Well I've managed to implement a token based authentication. The reason why the routes should not be accessible to anyone because the page will later be accessible in the www (just for our company use). So I've anyone had a network sniffer he could read probably everything from the server.